# htaccess redirect to https works only if the file exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, https

I have a wordpress site with SEO Redirection Plugin installed. This because I have  changed the site and I had to 301 redir some old pages.

Everything was working fine. Then I have also installed the SSL and I have changed the htaccess in order to redir from http to https. This is the file (as you can see, I have tested different solutions):

```
# RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /
# redirect 301 /implantologia.html https://www.mysite.it/implantologia/

# BEGIN GD-SSL
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(.+)$
# RewriteRule ^$ https://www.mysite.it/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^mysite\.it$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=300"
</IfModule>
# END GD-SSL

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This is what is happening now:

- if I check for an existing file using http, everything works and the user is redirected to https;
- if I check for a file that does NOT exist, using HTTPS, then my SEO Redirection plugin redir the request and everything is ok;
- if I check for a file that does NOT exist (for instance an old external link to mysite.it, using HTTP), the url in the browser remains the same and I get a 404 error. But if I resend the request, it works and I go to the right page.

Finally, if you click on an old http link you get a 404 error. However,  you will never experience this problem again after you have started to navigate on the site. I have a log of 404 error and it is full of errors that I wasn't able to see... until I started to browse Anonymously.

So, what kind of problem is this one? Is there a kind of cache? How come it doesn't work only for the first time access? Why htaccess doesn't redirect to https if the file requested doesn't exist?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You are using a plugin, rewrite and STS (Strict-Transport-Security) to deal with redirecting to https?? IMO all that together might cause strange issues. STS' nature is to redirect from http to https to compliant user agents. I would start by removing all plugins, STS and rewrite, and add one and see if it works correctly. You seem to have over kill.

Comment: Dear @PanamaJack, I am not using any plugin. I am only using htaccess where you can find the STS string. However, when I installed SSL, GoDaddy automatically made some changes to my account. You might be right but I have no idea where I should start to investigate from.